# What is the proper way of importing Angular 2 modules into the Angular2-Meteor package?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-http

I'm using the [Angular2-Meteor](http://www.angular-meteor.com/) package with Meteor 1.2.1 and want to import Angular 2 modules. I'm specifically trying to import angular2/http. Would it be proper to use node, atmosphere, typings or something else and what is the command? I'd rather not have to import the file(s) manually.